# TEXTJOIN of column with same values of other columns, Table references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, textjoin, excel-tables

On column D i want TEXTJOIN of column C.

1. delimiter is comma with a space after: ", "
2. the two conditions that have to be met are: same date in column A, same value in column B
3. This is a table so I prefer using references of the name of the columns (for example "Date")

any help will be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TEXTJOIN` in conjunction with `FILTER`.

Something like: `=TEXTJOIN(",",1, FILTER($C$2:$C$12, ($B$2:$B$12=B2)*($A$2:$A$12=A2))`

Note you can replace the ranges with the named ranges, and that '*' is used as a sort of `AND` within the `FILTER` function.

EDIT: to avoid repeating rows, you can wrap the entire function with an `IF` statement that checks for duplicates. Something like:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(
TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER($C$2:$C$12,($B$2:$B$12=$B12)*($A$2:$A$12=$A12))),D$1:D11,0)>0,""),
TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER($C$2:$C$12,($B$2:$B$12=$B12)*($A$2:$A$12=$A12))))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you :) very clear
I wrote this to write it only for the some of the rows:
=IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)=1,TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER([filename],([Fruit]=[@Fruit])*([Date]=[@Date]))),"")

I wonder if I can change the COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2) to table reference as well

Comment: No problem, see my edit for another way to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 2):

`=IF($B1<>$B2,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",0,$C2:INDEX($C2:$C$12,MATCH(1,--($B2:$B$12<>$B2),0)-1)),TEXTJOIN(",",0,$C2:$C$12)),"")`

The Formula indexes column C from the current row up until it finds a different value in column B (minus 1).
The IFERROR is for the last found in range, because it will not find a value in the range after that value that doesn't match that value anymore. To be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` for Excel versions prior to Office 365